# Sparse Kronecker Product of Pauli Matricies

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

Suppose I have a list of Pauli matrices (X, Z and I type)

```
paulis = {x,z,z,i,z,x,i,z};
```

I would like to compute a sparse array equivalent to
$$x \otimes z\otimes z \ldots \otimes z$$

In a non-sparse way this would be

```
ToPauliMatrices[v_] := v /. Thread[{i, x, y, z} -> PauliMatrix[{0, 1, 2, 3}]]
KroneckerProduct@@ToPauliMatrices[paulis]
```

In general, this makes a square matrix of dimension `{2^Length[paulis], 2^Length[paulis]}`, but only `2^Length[paulis]` elements are non-zero. This makes me think that there should be an efficient way to produce this directly as a set of sparse matrix rules. Any ideas would be appreciated. The function template would be

```
(* arr is a sparse array that represents an arbitrary product of Pauli matrices
pauli is a single pauli matrix (X, Z, or I)*)
SparsePauliProduct[arr_, pauli_] := ...
```

Comment: `KroneckerProduct @@ (SparseArray /@ ToPauliMatrices[paulis])` ?

Comment: Yup thanks, I did not realize Mathematica had an optimized `KroneckerProduct` for `SparseArray`. Thank you

Comment: Or with `{pm[i], pm[x], pm[y], pm[z]} = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[{0, 1, 2, 3}]]` you can then do `KroneckerProduct @@ pm /@ paulis`